# Joomla 3.3.6 user profile form validation

Tags: joomla3.3

I am trying to add validation to fields in user profile form.So I added

```
 <field
                    name="postal_code"
                    type="text"
                    id="postal_code"
                                    **class="validate-numeric"**
                    description="PLG_USER_PROFILE_FIELD_POSTAL_CODE_DESC"
                    filter="string"
                    label="PLG_USER_PROFILE_FIELD_POSTAL_CODE_LABEL"
                    size="30"                                
                            />
```

to plugins\user\profile\profiles\profile.xml.Its working fine with user registration.How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Create a class JFormRulePostal_code  extending JFormRule in libraries/joomla/form/rule/ and change type="postal_code" and class="postal_code.